# `op_name` parameter for `graphene_django`

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

The [django graphene documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/testing/) shows a test example like this:

```
class MyFancyTestCase(GraphQLTestCase):
    def test_some_query(self):
        response = self.query(
            '''
            query {
                myModel {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
            ''',
            op_name='myModel'
        )

        content = json.loads(response.content)

        # This validates the status code and if you get errors
        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)

        # Add some more asserts if you like
        ...
```

They don't have any API documentation for what `op_name` is, and what we should set it as. I tried to set it to my query name, but get the error:

```
[{'message': 'Unknown operation named "myQuery".'}]
```

Comment: The API documentation says: "If the query is a mutation or named query, you must supply the op_name.  For annon queries ("{ ... }"), should be None (default)", but I am using the name that I have supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

> If the query is a mutation or named query, you must supply the op_name.  For annon queries ("{ ... }"), should be None (default)

I am not sure how to create a "named query" with django graphene, but apparently my query is NOT a named query. Leaving `op_name` as `None` got my query to work via my unit test.

Answer (score 2):

Operation name is only needed when there are multiple operations in the query string. You only have one operation so the default (None) is fine.

https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/execute/#operation-name